# Как создать функцию для сохранение измененного изображения, Canvas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, pillow

Нужно чтобы работала функция `save_file()`.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


window = Tk()
window.title("Watermarking App")
window.geometry("1920x1280")
window.resizable(0, 0)
window.option_add("*tearOff", FALSE)

def open_file():
    global image
    file_path = fd.askopenfilename()
    canvas = Canvas(bg="white", width=1200, height=1200)
    canvas.pack(expand=True)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(f"{file_path}"))
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, anchor=NW, image=image)

def save_file():
    pass

def select_font():
    window.tk.call("tk", "fontchooser", "show")
    
main_menu = Menu()
file_menu = Menu()
edit_menu = Menu()

main_menu.add_cascade(label="File", menu=file_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="Edit", menu=edit_menu)
main_menu.add_cascade(label="View")

file_menu.add_command(label="Save", command=save_file)
file_menu.add_command(label="Open", command=open_file)
file_menu.add_separator()
file_menu.add_command(label="Exit")

edit_menu.add_command(label="Добавить текст")
edit_menu.add_command(label="Выбор шрифта", command=select_font)

window.config(menu=main_menu)
window.mainloop()
```

---

Update:
Нашел такое решение, сохраняет изменения (когда добавляют текст), но приходится открывать через фотошоп).

```
def save_file(): 
    canvas.postscript(file="photo.ps", colormode="color") 
    img = Image.open("photo.ps") 
    img.save("photo.png", "png")
```

Comment: да, сейчас тут менять особо нечего, нужно чтоб работала функция save_file()

Comment: Чтобы она работала, в ней нужно написать код. Что конкретно не получается?

Comment: @insolor 
def save_file():
    canvas.postscript(file="photo.ps", colormode="color")
    img = Image.open("photo.ps")
    img.save("photo.png", "png")      нашел такое решение, сохраняет изменения ( когда добавляют текст) но приходится открывать через фотошоп)

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
...
ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(filename)
...
```

---

```
from tkinter import Canvas, Tk,LAST, Button, filedialog, messagebox
import PIL.ImageGrab as ImageGrab
from math import cos, sin, radians, pi


root = Tk()
root.title('Рисование и сохранение, Canvas')
root.geometry('600x620+400+50')
root.config(bg='black')
root.resizable(0,0)


canvas = Canvas(root, bg='black', width=570, height=570, relief='raised', bd=4)
canvas.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=2, padx=5, pady=5)

j =0
def drawing(j): 
    canvas.create_oval(150, 150, 450, 450, 
        fill='black', outline='orange', width=6, 
        activeoutline='dark violet', activefill='gray12')
    canvas.create_oval(180, 180, 420, 420, 
        fill='black', outline='magenta', width=6, 
        activeoutline='dark violet', activefill='gray12')

    for y in range(12):
        canvas.create_text(300 - 133*sin(((y+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            300 - 133*cos(((y+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            text= '•', 
            font=('Arial',15, 'bold'), fill='deep sky blue')
    for x in range(12):
        canvas.create_text(300 - 133*sin(((x+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            300  - 133*cos(((x+1)*2*pi)/12), 
            text= '☼', 
            font=('Arial',25, 'bold'), fill='yellow')

    # линии  ☼
    canvas.create_line(300, 300, 300 + 120*sin(radians(j+180)), 
        150 - 120*cos(radians(j+180)), fill='green2',width=3,arrow=LAST)
    canvas.create_line(300, 300, 150 + 120*sin(radians(j+90)), 
        300 - 120*cos(radians(j+90)), fill='green2',width=3,arrow=LAST)
    canvas.create_line(300, 300, 450 + 120*sin(radians(j-90)), 
        300 - 120*cos(radians(j-90)), fill='green2',width=3,arrow=LAST)
    canvas.create_line(300, 300, 300 + 120*sin(radians(j)), 
        450 - 120*cos(radians(j)), fill='green2',width=3,arrow=LAST)

    canvas.create_oval(290, 290, 310, 310, fill='gold' , outline='black', width=2)


def save_drawing():
    try: 
        filename = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(defaultextension='.png')
        x = root.winfo_rootx() + canvas.winfo_x()
        y = (root.winfo_rooty() + canvas.winfo_y())

        x1 = x + canvas.winfo_width()
        y1 = y + canvas.winfo_height()

        ImageGrab.grab().crop((x, y, x1, y1)).save(filename)
        messagebox.showinfo('Сохранить рисунок',
            'Изображение сохранено в: ' + str(filename) )
    except:
        messagebox.showerror('Сохранить рисунок', 
            'Изображение не сохранено\nОшибка')

def start_drawing():
    global j
    j = j + 5
    drawing(j)
    x = canvas.after(100, start_drawing)
    if j == 360:
        canvas.after_cancel(x)
        j = 0

Button(root, text='Начинать рисование', 
    bg='green2', command=start_drawing).grid(column=0, row=1, pady=2)
Button(root, text='Сохранить изображение', 
    bg='blue', fg='white', command=save_drawing).grid(column=1,row=1, padx=50)

root.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: После диалога выбора файла возможно еще пауза какая-то нужна или `root.update()`, а то `ImageGrab.grab()` и сам диалог может захватить: https://i.stack.imgur.com/38xan.png. Как вариант, просто диалог сохранения показывать уже после захвата изображения.